# Arduino Due 9-bit serial - Can core Due Libraries be modified to get this functionality similar to Mega and Uno?

Tags: serial, arduino-due, hardware

Need help to see if I can get an Arduino due to receive and send 9-bit com as already implemented on AVRs like Uno, Mega and even teensy boards, by modifying hardware serial cores. Have not found any similar references for this for the due? Is the due capable of 9-bit com?

Comment: What I mean by Hardware Serial Cores are files in the Arduino IDE. Ex. Serial.Hardware.cpp, etc.

Comment: If it's using UART then it's not possible (=> pins 0/1). If it's using USART (all other serials), then it's possible.